# how to get selected/clicked value in calendar_date_select_tagin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how to get selected/clicked value in calendar_date_select_tag in rails and pass it as params in controller (as format yyyy-mm-dd)as remote_function? I have tried like this

```
   <%= calendar_date_select_tag "calendar", @time,
                             :embedded => true,
                             :onchange => remote_function(
                                     :method => :get,
                                     :url => {:action => "show", :id => @vehicle},
                                     :with => "'mtg_date='+($(this).val()",
                                     :loading => "$('date_spinner').setStyle({visibility: 'visible'});",
                                     :complete => "$('date_spinner').setStyle({visibility: 'hidden'});" ) %>
```

But it seems to be not working

Comment: Are you getting any errors on console?.

Comment: I see this `:with => "'mtg_date='+($(this).val()",`  ending brace is missing `)`

Comment: I tried like this... <%= calendar_date_select_tag "calendar", @time,
                             :embedded => true,
                             :onchange => remote_function(
                                     :method => :get,
                                     :url => {:action => "show", :id => @vehicle},
                                     :with => "'mtg_date='+($F(this))",
                                     :loading => "$('date_spinner').setStyle({visibility: 'visible'});",
                                     :complete => "$('date_spinner').setStyle({visibility: 'hidden'});" ) %>

Comment: But the above is passing date as September 9, 2013 and in my db the date is saved as yyyy-mm-dd and I need to compare the params date in db and retieve the records

Answer (score 0):

Write following in the environment.rb/application.rb depending on your rails version

```
CalendarDateSelect.format = :american
```

Ref [this](https://github.com/timcharper/calendar_date_select/blob/master/lib/calendar_date_select/calendar_date_select.rb) for other formats